# Job transfer politics

Tags: new-job, job-change, title, job-description, new-hires

I started a new job two weeks ago and already know that my skills do not align with the job description. I do not have an Accounting background and feel as though I made the wrong decision in accepting the offer because I did not realize that Accounting is the primary focus of this role.

However, there is a perfect role that opened up on my team that follows my career goals. The role is highly analytical, which is the same role that I had at the previous company I worked for and my education is closely aligned with the skills needed to do the job. I have researched this topic online and the advice generally reads to stick it out for 6 months and then re-assess the job transfer scenario. Since the division within my team that is hiring is very small, the opportunity for this perfect role to come up is rare. If I have the opportunity to use my skills and do what is best for the company, why not express my interest and benefit my team, career track, and the overall company?

That being said, I discussed my interest with the hiring manager, who mentioned that I would be great for the role and to speak with my boss about the possibility to transfer roles. Please note that my boss is the hiring manager's boss, which complicates the dynamic in terms of getting what I want out of the situation.

Then, I discussed my interest with my boss, who did not share the same enthusiasm as the hiring manager. She felt that I was being deceptive in accepting an offer to do my current job and expressing interest in transferring roles. She failed to acknowledge the fact that I do not know how to do my job intuitively. She mentioned that I can apply for the job that I want and if I do not get the role then I will continue to do my current job. She also said that the hiring manager has the final say as to who will be hired for the role that I want.

In retrospect, I have no regrets to have expressed my interest in a role that I know I can do and will enjoy. However, I have created awkwardness with my boss because she does not see my pain and only sees the pain she will take on in filling my current role. The problem is that by getting my way, I make the biggest impact to the company and team dynamic.

Why would I want to stay at a company that does not use my talents and skills in the right way? If they decide to turn me down for the role that I really want, why would I stay working in my current role?

Any thoughts?

Comment: How certain are you that you aren't making the same mistake you just made a few weeks ago in applying within Accounting yet don't want to work in that role? There can be the appearance of being picky that could backfire here.

Comment: Apparently on this site if you have a problem, you are the problem. My previous role is for the role that I want and my skills are purely analytical. I admit that I should have been more skeptical when one of the interviewers said the role was only 30% Accounting. You never know until you get into the role. How would you like to do your job in German?

Comment: I got the job. Thanks everyone for your lack of faith. Now, I will be retiring my services with regard to this website.

Comment: Congrats and best wishes.

Answer (score 7):

> Why would I want to stay at a company that does not use my talents and skills in the right way? If they decide to turn me down for the role that I really want, why would I stay working in my current role?

For the money is one simple answer.

It's not really up to you to decide what role you want to fulfill in a company, it's the bosses.

So apply for the job if you want to, knowing that this may be viewed negatively because of the bosses perception that you seem to have misrepresented yourself getting the original job, plus they will have to fill your current role, which they thought they already had done at some expense. Or stick to the job you have right now.

Realistically your chances seem slim of landing it, you haven't proved yourself to be very committed and you will be making a couple of headaches for the boss which they might view as just a bit too much for a new hire.

Comment: I have never worked for a company that would let an employee of around two weeks transfer to a different position. You have to have a track record at that company to get an internal transfer unless you actual job is being eliminated.To even ask is really unrealistic and has already created a situation where the boss is upset with the OP. The chances of getting the job are slim. It would be far better to expend the energy to learn the accounting parts of the job,

Answer (score 4):

Your question is asking for an opinion, which will get it closed. Rephrasing it would be advisable.

I don't really see the issue. Your boss said that you can apply for the new position, and that the hiring manager makes the final decisions as to whom to choose.

If applying for that job is what you want, then go for it. It seems like you'd have a pretty good chance to get that job.

If you think that the political fallout of switching roles is going to be too big, then start looking for a new job, or tough out your current one. We can't know how good you'll be at it, or how much you're going to enjoy it, so how can we advise?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way a manager who has just spent their limited headcount and time bringing you on board is going to be happy with you saying "sorry, but the job I really want is..." From their point of view this isn't any better than your quitting entirely. You are making a LOT of extra work for them, when if you had not accepted the job in the first place they'd have hired someone who wouldn't have wasted scarce resources. Never mind how much more you could do for the company, you're doing harm to his department.

It's really going to depend on whether both management chains -- up to the point where they meet at a single manager -- agree with you that the reassignment is the best thing for the company. And the difficulty of the move gets greater the more levels you have to go through to find that shared boss.